# Material-UI how to manipulate styles for DialogContent and Dialog?

Tags: css, material-ui, modal-dialog, react-final-form

Currently I am facing an awkward situation:

I want to make the `dialogContent`'s `overflow: auto` so my modal becomes scrollable if the content exceed the height of the `dialog`. However, there's a dropdown menu that I'd like it to display normally, but because `overflow: auto`, I have to not only scroll down the dropdown menu, but also the dialog itself. Can someone help me with this?

```
const dialogStyle = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      width: '100vw',
    },
    dialog: {
      overflow: 'visible',
    },
    dialogContent: {
      overflow: 'auto',
    },
  }),
)
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might have the same issue - I figured the answer myself.

So.. The best way to resolve this, is to add an attribute: `<Dialog scroll='body' />` and keep the both `dialog` and `dialogContent`'s overflow as visible.